# (Free) Dictionary Softwares on Windows

Tags: windows, dictionary

On Mac OS X, its native dictionary application works well for me (especially the added Japanese dictionary in Leopard). I am looking for an equivalent English dictionary software on Windows. I have tried online solutions such as "define:Google" in Google and other websites but my internet connection doesn't allow prompt result, so an offline solution is better for me.

A free software is welcome. Also international support (Japanese, Thai, ...) is a plus.

Comment: There are currently close votes for this Q, I don't think it should be closed & deleted, if anything it could be moved to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Wordweb](http://wordweb.info/free/) (Free for personal use)

Comment: Nice find!

Comment: Great application! Allow me to wait for more answers before accepting yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[Babiloo](http://code.google.com/p/babiloo/) is free and open source. It supports formats of other dictionary applications as well so you can import a myriad of dictionaries.

> - Runs on most of the platforms, Windows, Linux, MacOS, Nokia S60
>     (>1.9).
> - Supports dictionaries in SDictionary, and StarDict formats.
> - HTML displaying for the supported dictionaries.
> - Able to download more dictionaries within the application.
> - Translated into more than 30 languages

[image]

---

[StarDict](http://code.google.com/p/stardict-3/) is another popular one:

Note: In 2016, this message appears on the old [StarDict](http://stardict.sourceforge.net/) site:

> The original StarDict project has recently been removed from
>   SourceForge due to copyright infringement reports. Most of the files
>   were lost with the demise of the project. The project has re-emerged
>   here since then, though the legal issues may never have been resolved.
>
> StarDict hasn't seen any active development for many years, while the
>   world around hasn't stood still. The following is the list of
>   alternatives appeared during that time. You are advised to take a look
>   and try them:
>
> - [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/) - designed as a StarDict successor, it supports its format, lots of other formats (Lingvo, Babylon etc), features tabbed
>     browsing, morphology, live pronunciations, Wikipedia and so on. The
>     program is constantly being improved and worked on.
> - [Babiloo](http://code.google.com/p/babiloo/) - a free open source software developed to read offline dictionaries. Runs on most platforms. Supports StarDict and
>     SDictionary formats.
> - [LightLang](http://code.google.com/p/lightlang/) - another system of electronic dictionaries (Linux only).

[image]

---

[JaLingo](http://jalingo.sourceforge.net/) is another one. It's written in Java making it highly portable:

[image]

Comment: I tried twice but I could not install this software. DOn't know why.

Comment: Added some more options for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried [this](http://multitran.ru/DownLoad/mt_big_demo.exe) one which is called MultiTran. It has demo version(absolutely free) and full version(with some costs). Demo version only restricts with number of words for each language, but it has no any trial period which is very good. Here are language database for demo version:

1. English-Russian-English 1.000.000
2. German-Russian-German   400.000
3. French-Russian-French   150.000
4. Spanish-Russian-Spanish 70.000
5. Netherlands-Russian-Nether. 30.000
6. Italian-Russian-Italian 67.000
7. Estonian-Russian-Estonian   26.000
8. Latvian-Russian-Latvian     25.000