# Plaintext natural language dictionaries

Tags: language, dictionary, plaintext

Does anyone know where I can find a source for free plaintext or xml natural language dictionaries. I am working on a program for memorization and I'd like to make some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by "dictionary", you mean just a database of the words that make up the language? If so, I'd try the dictionaries shipped with open source spell checkers like [aspell](http://misc.aspell.net/wiki/English_Dictionaries). Also take a look at [this Super User post](https://superuser.com/questions/33012/free-dictionary-softwares-on-windows), you may be able to use the dictionaries from some of the open source tools mentioned there.